# Change a function dynamically in C

Tags: javascript, c, function

I would like to know if there is an equivalent in C (for a `void` function) to this javascript code:

```
var myFunction;
myFunction = function(){
    //Some code
}
```

Comment: Don't know javascript but it seems similar to function pointers in c

Comment: Not quite. Anonymous functions are a little more than just that. They can capture their context (i.e. they can be defined on the spot -- like above) and can capture the local variables of the (outer) function in which they are defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really equivalent (because C is a static language without support for anonymous or nested functions) but you can have a variable that is a *pointer* to a function, and make it point to different compiled functions matching the type of the variable.

Very simple and basic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function1(void)
{
    printf("function1\n");
}

void function2(void)
{
    printf("function2\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    // Declare a variable that is a pointer to a function taking no arguments
    // and returning nothing
    void (*ptr_to_fun)(void);

    ptr_to_fun = &function2;
    ptr_to_fun();

    ptr_to_fun = &function1;
    ptr_to_fun();

    return 0;
}
```

The above program will print out

```
function2
function1
```

Comment: Not really equivalent, indeed, because this can not be defined inline (inside another function). Anonymous functions can even capture the local variables of the outer function, etc.

Comment: FWIW, Delphi is a static language too, but it can do anonymous functions. The real problem is that C is a procedural and not an OO language. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In C you can use a function pointer:

```
void the_function(void) {
    // ...
}

void (*my_function)(void) = the_function;
```

C doesn't support anonymous functions so your function needs to have a name by itself (here I use `the_function`).

You call the function via function pointer like you'd call an ordinary function:

```
my_function();
```

---

However this practice is subject to limitations. First of all, you must know the number and the type of arguments that the function expects. Calling it with wrong arguments will invoke undefined behaviour. Also, you need to know the actual type of return value as well. And these need to be known at compile-time. You need to use [tricks like `libffi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263745/in-c-given-a-variable-list-of-arguments-how-to-build-a-function-call-using-the) to call a function whose signature you do not know at runtime.

Comment: if you want to use a variable number of arguments you could pass it an array and the number of elements. it might be possible to use variadic functions (à la printf()) that take a variable list of arguments.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane true. Though, for variadic functions the function would have to accept variable arguments, and thus you'd know it at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behaviour of a certain function call, you could operate on a function pointer instead of calling the function directly:

- Init function pointer fp1 with a reference to a()
- Call fp1
- Overwrite function pointer with a reference to b()
- Call fp1