# Use printf for ternary operator arguments with mixed types

Tags: c, types, printf, conditional-operator, mixed

I have a tricky, but interesting question. Hang in there!

Let's assume I write embedded code, and I am in a system where I have to store values in 16bit unsigned to be compatible with other systems. Some values have a decimal part, but luckily I know the position of the separator in advance (fixed point).

Now let's consider this structure:

```
typedef struct{

   // pointer to a function that computes the "real" value
   float (*getRealValue)(void);

   // pointer to a function that computes a "stringified" value
   bool (*getCustomString)(char *);

} var_info_t;
```

And let's declare one variable var1, which is a temperature:

```
uint16_t var1 = 1530; // means 15.3°C

float var1_toFloat(void){ return (float)var1/100; } // should return 15.3

var_info_t var1_info = { .getRealValue = var1_toFloat, .getCustomString = NULL };
```

and another variable var2, which happens to be more like a boolean:

```
uint16_t var2 = 1; // means Enabled

bool var2_toString(char* buffer){  // should write "Enabled"
   if(buffer) sprintf(buffer, "%s", var2 ? "Enabled" : "Disabled");
   return true;
}
var_info_t var2_info = { .getRealValue = NULL, .getCustomString = var2_toString };
```

Now I want to display these values together on a screen, with some fancy formatting that can change depending of where these value are written on the screen.

*(I just have to call `TEXT_SetText(int widget_id, char* text)` to update my GUI widgets.)*

What I want to accomplish is to create a "wrapper" to *TEXT_SetText()* like this...

```
static char text[128], buf[2][32];

#define GET_VAR_AUTO(var_info, i) \
  ((var_info.getCustomString != NULL && var_info.getCustomString(buf[i])) ? buf[i] : \
   (var_info.getRealValue != NULL ? var_info.getRealValue() : 0))

void my_TEXT_SetText(int widget_id, char* format, var_info_t a, var_info_t b){
   snprintf(text, sizeof(text), format, GET_VAR_AUTO(a, 0), GET_VAR_AUTO(b, 1));
   TEXT_SetText(widget_id, text);
}
```

...so that calling **`my_TEXT_SetText(0, "Regulator is %s at %.1f\260C", var2_info, var1_info);`**

will display a nice **`Regulator is Enabled at 15.3°C`** inside my box.

The real advantage here is that you can **update the text in real-time** just by calling this same function periodically from "anywhere" (without "knowing anything" about the variables or their values). Also you can simply expand the number of variables inside the same text by increasing the number of `snprintf` arguments.

**The problem:** the GET_VAR_AUTO macro is not syntactically correct because it mixes `char*` from `buf[i]` and `float` from `getRealValue()` in the possible results of the ternary operator:

> error: type mismatch in conditional expression

**BUT,** knowing that `sprintf` is a **variadic function**, that treats its arguments according to the types given in the format string (%f, %s, ... thanks to the `va_arg()` function), **is there a way to find a common abstract type for the ternary operator** which would be accepted by the `sprintf` ?

I tried a lot of things but I can't get the `char*` and `float` to work simultaneously.

*(Unfortunately I'm using C, not C++)*

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to do here, but it sounds like a job for [*Generic selection*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

Comment: I know it's hard but I can't find a way to explain it more easily. And yes I have to clarify that I'm in C, not C++... :(

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't believe it is possible simply with generic selection... considering that OP wants to support function calls with any arity and possibly many types...

Comment: @Motla This is standard in C11. Yet maybe won't be helpful in your case

Comment: @EugeneSh. my bad, you're right. Ok then; I will explore it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Motla, IMO, the goal of printing _without "knowing anything" about the variables or their values_ is tied to a certian approach using `?:` and has troubles answered below.  OTOH, if you are willing to achieve _without "knowing anything"_ with another approach, consider `_Generic`.   Example: [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485).

Comment: @Motla I've edited my answer to better highlight why it is impossible to make this work on x86-64 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there simply isn't any generic type, and it cannot be done in C except in very special cases.

For example floating point arguments are passed in floating point/SSE registers on x86-64 for example, whereas integer arguments in integer registers. There is no way of passing a variable argument that is passed as "both" in variable arguments, because in a function call like

```
printf("%f %d",  f,  d  );
       R1        F1  R2
```

The arguments would be passed in two general-purpose registers and one floating point register like so, whereas in

```
printf("%d %f",  d,  f  );
       R1        R2  F1
```

they would be passed in the *same* registers again!

Indeed,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%f %s\n", "hello world", 2.5);
}
```

compiled with GCC for x86-64/Linux, and run, will not print any random garbage but exactly `2.50000 hello world`. So on x86-64 the most you could do is to pass the *last* argument in both a floating point and a general purpose register.

---

What you could do is to write your *own* `printf`-like function that would accept *pointers to void* for the arguments, then dereference them based on the actual type.

It will still be quite tricky.

If you're really desperate, consider trying [libffi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263745/in-c-given-a-variable-list-of-arguments-how-to-build-a-function-call-using-the).

Comment: Ok then :) great answer, thank you! I will wait for some miracle but if not coming I will consider it as accepted.

Comment: "*you could have your own printf-like function*” 

Answer (score 2):

Define

```
#define FLOAT_STR_SIZE_MAX (32) /* or what ever you feel suits */
#define FTOA(b, s, x) \
  (snprintf(b, s, "%f", x), b)
```

and replace

```
 (var_info.getRealValue != NULL ? var_info.getRealValue() : 0)
```

by

```
 FTOA((char[FLOAT_STR_SIZE_MAX]){'\0'},
   FLOAT_STR_SIZE_MAX,
   (var_info.getRealValue != NULL ? var_info.getRealValue() : 0.))
```

:-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't get it work. The idea is to convert the float to char* ? Where goes (char[FLOAT_STR_SIZE_MAX]){'\0'} after snprintf() writes it ? Do I have to change %f to %s in my format variable ?

Comment: @Motla Yes, your final conversion specifier needs to be an `'s'`.

Comment: ok in this case it is simpler to forget about the getRealValue() function and only use string functions everywhere, forgetting about mixed types... doesn't answer the original question but I guess it's what I'm going to do anyway. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Motla the compound stays on the stack until the current scope has been left.