# Use snprintf() with separated input buffers in C

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

I try to outsource the input buffers of my snprintf() function:

So how to translate this working example:

```
struct ElementStruct {
    char element1[10];
    char element2[10];
}elementStruct;

char rxTxBuffer[30] = {0};

snprintf(rxTxBuffer, 30, "{ %s %s }", elementStruct.element1, elementStruct.element2);
```

To this not working example:

```
struct ElementStruct {
    char element1[10];
    char element2[10];
}elementStruct;

char rxTxBuffer[30] = {0};

char string[] = {"{ %s %s }"};
const char* restrict elements[] = {elementStruct.element1, elementStruct.element2};

snprintf(rxTxBuffer, 30 ,string, *elements);
```

Comment: C doesn't allow argument spreading from an array. The closest you can get is `vsnprintf()`, but it use a `va_list` rather than an array; it's useful for writing your own `printf`-like functions that get variable numbers of arguments.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54366443/1848654.

Comment: Thanks for your hints, but I'm searching for a solution in C

Comment: ... er, yes? What did you think we were talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I thought vsnprintf() is only included in C++.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the question it was closed as duplicate of.

Comment: Wow. Somebody really checks!

Comment: Why do yo want to do that? From looking at the two code snippets, the 2nd is even more typing.

Comment: BTW this `char string[] = {"{ %s %s }"};` should be `char string[] = "{ %s %s }";`.