# How does the particular C function work?

Tags: c, printf, overloading

I am trying to learn C and am very confused already.

In the OOP languages i have used there exists the ability to perform method overloading, where the same function could have different parameter types and call whichever was the most appropriate.

Now in C i know that this is not the case so i cant figure out the following problem, How  printf() works.

For example:

```
char chVar = 'A';
int intVar = 123;
float flVar = 99.999;

printf("%c - %i - %f \n",chVar, intVar, flVar);
printf("%i - %f - %c \n",intVar, flVar, chVar);
printf("%f - %c - %i \n",flVar, chVar, intVar);
```

Now as C does'nt support function overloading, How does printf manage to take any number of arguments, of any type, and then work correctly with them?

I have tried to find the printf() working by downloading the glibc source package but can quite seem to find it, though i'll keep looking.

Could anyone here explain how C performs the above task?

Comment: If you want to know more, read up on calling conventions and the stack

Comment: Your question is about C, but you say "I am trying to learn C++."  If you are trying to learn C++, it's best to start by avoiding the C parts of the language (and stay at the higher levels of abstraction that C++ affords), then once you are comfortable with that, to dig into other parts of the language.

Comment: If you don't want to have to worry about this then pass `-Wformat` as an argument to g++. Other compilers should, I think/hope/expect, have similar warnings. This will cause the compiler to check that the types do match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ function definitions without assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442966/c-c-function-definitions-without-assembly)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C supports a type of function signature called "varargs" meaning "variable (number of) arguments".  Such a function must have at least one required argument.  In the case of `printf`, the format string is a required argument.

Generally, on a stack-based machine, when you call any C function, the arguments are pushed onto the stack from right-to-left.  In this way, the first argument to the function is that found on the "top" of the stack, just after the return address.

There are C macros defined which allow you to retrieve the variable arguments.

The key points are:

- There is no type-safety for the variable arguments.  In the case of `printf()`, if the format string is wrong, the code will read invalid results from memory, possibly crashing.
- The variable arguments are read through a pointer which is incremented through the memory containing those arguments.
- The argument pointer must be initialized with `va_start`, incremented with `va_arg`, and released with `va_end`.

I have posted a ton of code you may find interesting on the related question:

[Best Way to Store a va_list for Later Use in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562992/best-way-to-store-a-va-list-for-later-use-in-c-c/1565162#1565162)

Here's a skeleton of a `printf()` which only formats integers ("%d"):

```
int printf( const char * fmt, ... )
{
    int d;  /* Used to store any int arguments. */
    va_list args;  /* Used as a pointer to the next variable argument. */

    va_start( args, fmt );  /* Initialize the pointer to arguments. */

    while (*fmt)
    {
        if ('%' == *fmt)
        {
            fmt ++;

            switch (*fmt)
            {
                 case 'd':  /* Format string says 'd'. */
                            /* ASSUME there is an integer at the args pointer. */

                     d = va_arg( args, int);
                     /* Print the integer stored in d... */
                     break;
             }
        }
        else 
           /* Not a format character, copy it to output. */
        fmt++;
    }

    va_end( args );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Internally, `printf` will (at least usually) use some macros from stdarg.h. The general idea is (a greatly expanded version of) something like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_vfprintf(FILE *file, char const *fmt, va_list arg) {

    int int_temp;
    char char_temp;
    char *string_temp;
    char ch;
    int length = 0;

    char buffer[512];

    while ( ch = *fmt++) {
        if ( '%' == ch ) {
            switch (ch = *fmt++) {
                /* %% - print out a single %    */
                case '%':
                    fputc('%', file);
                    length++;
                    break;

                /* %c: print out a character    */
                case 'c':
                    char_temp = va_arg(arg, int);
                    fputc(char_temp, file);
                    length++;
                    break;

                /* %s: print out a string       */
                case 's':
                    string_temp = va_arg(arg, char *);
                    fputs(string_temp, file);
                    length += strlen(string_temp);
                    break;

                /* %d: print out an int         */
                case 'd':
                    int_temp = va_arg(arg, int);
                    itoa(int_temp, buffer, 10);
                    fputs(buffer, file);
                    length += strlen(buffer);
                    break;

                /* %x: print out an int in hex  */
                case 'x':
                    int_temp = va_arg(arg, int);
                    itoa(int_temp, buffer, 16);
                    fputs(buffer, file);
                    length += strlen(buffer);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            putc(ch, file);
            length++;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

int my_printf(char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    int length;

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    length = my_vfprintf(stdout, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return length;
}

int my_fprintf(FILE *file, char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    int length;

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    length = my_vfprintf(file, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return length;
}


#ifdef TEST 

int main() {
    my_printf("%s", "Some string");
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Fleshing it out does involve quite a bit of work -- dealing with field width, precision, more conversions, etc. This is enough, however, to at least give a flavor of how you retrieve varying arguments of varying types inside your function.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: perhaps you could explain what you think is wrong?

Comment: You skipped ahead to the part where a va_list has already been created.  That's not automatic, but your answer would make it seem so.  It may be (probably not, but possible I grant you), that printf() is a wrapper around my_vprintf() as you gave the example.  But the important knowledge is how to create a va_list, using va_start and the final non-variable argument.  Skipping that part is a non-answer on the order of "wrong."

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I didn't "skip" anything of the sort. If you look further down the code, you'll find the `my_printf` and `my_fprintf`, which do the calls the `va_start` and `va_end`.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I just did enough of an edit that you should be able to un-do the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

(Don't forget that, if you're using gcc (and g++?), you can pass `-Wformat` in the compiler options to get the compiler to check that the types of the arguments match the formatting. I hope other compilers have similar options.)

> Could anyone here explain how C performs the above task?

Blind faith. It assumes that you have ensured that the types of the arguments match perfectly with the corresponding letters in your format string. When `printf` is called, all the arguments are represented in binary, unceremoniously concatenated together, and passed effectively as a single big argument to `printf`. If they don't match, you'll have problems. As `printf` iterates through the format string, every time it see `%d` it will take 4 bytes from the arguments (assuming 32-bit, it would be 8 bytes for 64-bit ints of course) and it will interpret them as an integer.

Now maybe you actually passed a `double` (typically taking up twice as much memory as an `int`), in which case `printf` will just take 32 of those bits and represented them as an integer. Then the next format field (maybe a `%d`) will take the rest of the double.

So basically, if the types don't match perfectly you'll get badly garbled data. And if you're unlucky you will have undefined behaviour.